Next.js 14 : How do I pass a foreign key along with formData to a server action?
In my Next.js app, I have a form to create a new recipe (new-recipe-form.tsx). I need to associate this recipe with the Cook record (id is cookId). I am using Next.js server actions along with useFormState. In the server action 'newRecipe', I am creating the meal record by accessing formData and saving to db.
My question is how do I pass the cookId from the form to the server action so that I can link the recipe record to the cook?
// recipe-actions.ts
'use server';

export async function newRecipe(previousData, formData){
  const recipe = {
    title: formData.get('title'),
  }

  // Code to validate with Zod here
  // Prisma code to save to postgresql here 
}

// new-recipe-form.tsx
'use client';
import { newRecipe } from '@/lib/actions/recipe-actions';
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from 'react-dom';
import classes from './new-meal-form.module.css';
import { ButtonSubmit } from '../forms/button-submit';

interface NewRecipeProps {
  cookId: string,
}

export const NewRecipeForm: React.FC<NewRecipeProps> = ({
  cookId,
}) => {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(newRecipe, { message: ""} );

  return (
    <>
      <main className={classes.main}>
        <form
          className={classes.form}
          action={formAction}
        >
          <p>
            <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required />
          </p>
          <ButtonSubmit>
            Create Recipe
          </ButtonSubmit>
        </form>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default NewRecipeForm;


https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#passing-additional-arguments  this helps?

@cmgchess Thank you, your answer helped. I modified code as per the documentation you pointed to.  I did the following  change in the client component
const newRecipeWithCookId = newRecipe.bind(null, cookId)
const [state, formAction] = useFormState(newRecipeWithCookId, { message: ""} );
Then in the server component, the action gets 3  arguments, which includes the cookId:
export async function newMeal(cookId, previousData, formData){
...
}
If you answer my Question, I can accept your answer.
